# How to plot new chart from already displayed highchart series

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, highcharts

I am tried to get the series from the already displayed highchart and use that series to plot a new chart in another one html div, i have written below code to achieve this,finally i get the series from existing graph but can't render to the new html div

```
var data = chart.series; // series from already displyed

jQuery('#commonModal_res').highcharts({
                    chart: { zoomType: 'x'},
                    title: { text: ""  },
                    subtitle: {  text: 'Click and drag in the plotted area to zoom in'   },
                    xAxis: { type: 'datetime'  },
                    legend: { enabled: false  },
                    series: data,
                     });
```

note : `throwing too many recursion error`

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xwcq0942/ please refer this

Comment: What plot are you trying to make? Another piechart?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you're trying to assign the complete and already built series object, instead of configuration object which is required. In order to make it work, you need to assign the configuration object by this way:

```
$('#new_con').highcharts({
  chart: { zoomType: 'x'},
  title: { text: ""  },
  subtitle: {  text: 'Click and drag in the plotted area to zoom in'   },
  xAxis: { type: 'datetime'  },
  legend: { enabled: false  },
  series:charts[0].userOptions.series,
});
```

Then your chart should be rendered properly.
Additionaly, you can access appropriate chart by the `Highcharts.charts` array on global Highcharts object, where all charts are stored, just like that:

```
series: Highcharts.charts[0].userOptions.series,
```

In this case creating new charts array is unnecessary.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cqfj5t34/

Comment: it's working fine, if we have multiple series on same chart then how it's works?

Comment: It's not a problem, because you assigning whole series object from the first chart, so it contains all series. http://jsfiddle.net/7atc1e00/